# why doesn't this mergesort algorithm work?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have tried the following code in C for mergesort but it just ends up giving me a segfault. Could somebody find the bug?

```
int mergesort(int* unsorted, int* sorted, int N) {
if (N==1) {
    *unsorted=*sorted;
    return 1;
}
else {
    int left[MAXLEN];
    int right[MAXLEN];
    int sleft[MAXLEN];
    int sright[MAXLEN];
    int k1 = fill(unsorted,left,0,N/2);
    int k2 = fill(unsorted,right,N/2,N);
    int l1 = mergesort(left,sleft,k1);
    int l2 = mergesort(right,sright,k2);
    merge(sorted,sleft,sright,l1,l2);
    return N;
}
}

void merge(int* sorted,int* left,int* right,int N1,int N2) {
int i1=N1;
int i2=N2;
while ((i1!=0) || (i2!=0)) {
    if (i1==0) {
        while ((i2--)!=0)
            *sorted++=*right++;
    }
    else if (i2==0) {
        while ((i1--)!=0)
            *sorted++=*left++;
    }
    else {
        if (*left < * right) {
            *sorted++=*left++;
            i1--;
        }
        else {
            *sorted++=*right++;
            i2--;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The fill function has been implemented as follows

```
int fill(int* from, int* to, int left, int right) {
int i = left;
from += i;
while (i<right) {
    *to++=*from++;
     i++;
}
return (right-left);
```

}

Could somebody explain whether it's a bug, or whether I haven't handled memory allocation properly?

Comment: @hatchet: The OP said it throws a segfault.

Comment: Can you tell us on what line the segfault occurs? and give us an example of the input on which it throws a segfault?

Comment: `mergesort` is a recursive function with a very big stack frame (`4 * MAXLEN * sizeof(int)`); possibly you ran out of stack space. To verify this, please compile with [stack overflow checking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Stack-Overflow-Checking.html) and re-test.

Comment: You miss `N <= 0`, and might want to review the case `1 == N`. Ruud has pointed out the amount of memory used by your implementation, let me add that appreciable more additional memory than the size of the input is waste. If you don't want to modify something, let the maintenance coder/compiler know: `int mergesort(int const * unsorted, …`. Your `fill()` copies - the name should reflect what's important in your eyes. Document using a [tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change the condition of merge() function

`while ((i1!=0) || (i2!=0))`

to

`while ((i1>0) || (i2>0))`

It will remove the segfault.

**Explanation :**
Suppose `i1=0` and `i2=1`. Then see what happens :

```
if (i1==0) {
        while ((i2--)!=0)
            *sorted++=*right++;
    }
```

When the compiler check `i2` it is 1. So condition `true`. Loop continues and it decrements `i2` by `1`. So now `i2=0`
in the next iteration when the compiler again check `i2` which is 0. Condition `false`. Loop breaks and as you see `i2` decrements by `1`. So `i2` becomes `i2=-1`.Because at first compiler checks `i2` then decrements.

So this `while ((i1!=0) || (i2!=0))` condition never fulfills and *sorted++ constantly increases and causes segmfault as you ran out of stack space.

- Now change the first condition of mergesort() function.

That is:

```
if (N==1) { 
    *unsorted=*sorted;
    return 1;
}
```

to

```
if (N==1) {
    *sorted=*unsorted;
    return 1;
}
```

**Explanation :**  If you do the 1st one, sorted array will never change and you will never get sorted output. So when there is only 1 element left we can simply copy the element of unsorted array to the sorted.

I think this will solve the problem :)

Comment: It would help if you could explain *why* you think these will solve the segfault problem. (Teach a man to fish ...)

Comment: To stress: use `while (not ready)` (`(0 < --i)`) in favour of `while (not(first beyond))`.

Comment: Always a pleasure :)